Auditd not logging certain user management events
I'm trying to track user management changes such as adding user to groups.
I'm currently testing it on 2 machines and receive different results:

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Rocky Linux 9.2 (Blue Onyx)

On Rocky Linux everything works as expected, after running usermod -aG adm my_user I can see a corresponding audit entry:
type=USER_MGMT msg=audit(1716370963.544:1987): pid=4177990 uid=0 auid=1003 ses=10 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=add-user-to-group grp="adm" acct="my_user" exe="/usr/sbin/usermod" hostname=rockylab addr=? terminal=pts/1 res=success'UID="root" AUID="*****"
When I do the same operation on Ubuntu, I find the following logs related to this activity:
/var/log/audit/audit.log
type=USER_CHAUTHTOK msg=audit(1716371280.662:84): pid=470619 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=73 subj=unconfined msg='op=adding user to group acct="my_user" exe="/usr/sbin/usermod" hostname=ubuntulab addr=? terminal=pts/1 res=success'UID="root" AUID="*****"
/var/log/auth.log
May 22 09:48:00 ubuntulab usermod[470619]: add 'my_user' to group 'adm'
How can I unify the audit messages across both distributions?
Both systems are working on default auditd config (no custom rules added, when I tried comparing files in /etc/audit/ I did not find any meaningful differences). So the entries must be coming from somewhere else. I've read that it might be related to PAM configuration on debian, but did not have much success with it.
